# Pass additional data in DetailView Django

Tags: django

I have FBV where I am calculating time delta (td) and passing it in my context:

```
def update_moc(request, pk):
    moc = get_object_or_404(Moc, pk=pk)
    today = datetime.date.today()
    time = moc.initiation_date
    time_delta = today - time
    td=str(time_delta)
    initiator = moc.initiator
    status = moc.moc_status
    coordinator = moc.coordinators.filter(coordinator_name=request.user)
    
    if request.user.is_superuser or (initiator == request.user or coordinator) and status == 'draft':
    
        form = MocUpdateForm(request.POST or None, instance=moc)
        
        today = datetime.date.today()
        time = moc.initiation_date
        time_delta = today - time
        td=str(time_delta)
    
        if form.is_valid():
            moc.initiator = request.user
            form.save()
    
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('moc_content_detail', kwargs={'pk': pk}))
        else:
            return render(request, 'moc/moc_content.html', context={'moc':moc, 'form':form, 'td': td}) 
    
    else:
    
        raise Http404()
```

However for DetailView I am having CBV and want to pass same time_delta (td) as additional context, but failing how I can do it...
I tried few approaches to pass

```
class MocDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Moc
    template_name = 'moc/moc_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(MocDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['td'] = # This is where I need help


    def get_object(self, queryset=None):

        obj = super(MocDetailView, self).get_object(queryset=queryset)

        confidential = obj.confidential
        initiator = obj.initiator

        .....

        if self.request.user.is_superuser or initiator == self.request.user or verifier or coordinator or reviewer or approver or preimplement or authorizer or postimplement or closer and confidential == True:
            return obj

        elif not confidential:
            return obj      

        else:
            raise Http404()
```

Any hints please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `self.object` to calculate timedelta:

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(MocDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    time = self.object.initiation_date
    today = datetime.date.today()
    time_delta = today - time
    td=str(time_delta)
    context['td'] = td
    return context
```

This should work because Django assign the result of `get_object()` method to `self.object` variable. You can check the source code [here](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/#get).

Also Django passes object into `get_context_data` directly, so it's also possible to get it from `kwargs`:

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(MocDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    time = kwargs['object'].initiation_date
    # rest of the code
```